# Combine two images into one orientation issue

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I want to make an app where user can take picture with back camera, and then with front camera.

So, after that I get two bitmaps and I want to combine them into one image.

This code I use for front Camera parameters:

```
//Set up picture orientation for saving...
Camera.Parameters parameters = theCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setRotation(90);
frontCamera.setParameters(parameters);

//Set up camera preview and set orientation to PORTRAIT
        frontCamera.stopPreview();
        frontCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        frontCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        frontCamera.startPreview();
```

This code I use for taking picture with front camera

```
  cameraObject.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
```

Callback for taking picture with back camera

```
      PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        backBitmap = decodeBitampFromByte(data, 0, 800, 800);   

        frontCameraObject.release();  

        initFrontCamera();  

      }       
};
```

**NOTE:** Similar code is for taking picture with front camera. I get two bitmaps, and then I try to combine them with code below, but I get saved bitmap with wrong orientation.

This code I use for combing two bitamps: frontBitmap, backBitmap.

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s, String loc) 
{ 
Bitmap cs = null; 

int w = c.getWidth() + s.getWidth();
int h;
if(c.getHeight() >= s.getHeight()){
 h = c.getHeight();
}else{
 h = s.getHeight();
}
cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs); 

comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null);
comboImage.drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth, 0f, null);


    String tmpImg = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png";

    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(loc + tmpImg);
        cs.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("combineImages", "problem combining images", e);
    }           

       return cs; 
   }
```

**NOTE** Image with bottle of the water is taken with back camera, and other is with front camera.
[image]

Comment: Your saved bitmap has landscape orientation. Did you want it portrait? You have not told us how the combined bitmap should look like. What do you want?

Comment: Yes, I want it in the portrait. The upper part of the combined picture should have picture from back camera, and lower part of the combined picture should have picture from front camera.

Comment: Then do not add the widths like you do here: int w = c.getWidth() + s.getWidth(); Instead add the heigths. And rotate both bitmaps before in the right position (well if you want that).

Comment: I've tried to change code like this, but it still doesn't work, even I can't see front image.    int w;
    int h = c.getHeight() + s.getHeight();
    if(c.getHeight() >= s.getHeight()){
     w = c.getWidth();
    }else{
     w = s.getWidth();
    }

Comment: In the if statement you should compare the widths! And for the second drawBitmap() adjust x,y.

Comment: How I should adjust x,y of the second drawBitmap() ?

Comment: Now x,y is such that the second one comes to the right of the first one. Adjust them so the second comes under the first one.

Comment: Can you write code for that?

Comment: What are the values of x,y now?

Comment: I decode images at this size:         backBitmap = decodeBitampFromByte(data, 0, 800, 800);

Comment: That answer is wrong. Now you have for x,y c.getWidth, 0f. But you ment c.getWidth(), 0f.

Comment: I didn't understand you. X,Y of what?

Comment: I wrote "And for the second drawBitmap() adjust x,y." Your code has ...drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth, 0f, null); where c.getWidth() is the x coordinate and 0f the y coordinate. Here the left top corner of the second bitmap is drawn. You have to change that position.

Comment: Aha, I have changed that to this:     comboImage.drawBitmap(s, 0f, c.getWidth(), null);

Comment: You are expected to tell also if the second one is now under the first one and if all is ok. I suppose not because it has to be  comboImage.drawBitmap(s, 0f, c.getHeight(), null);

Comment: I have changed to that, it's almost finished, but it still has few more problems. Picture orientation, and that empty space on lower picture. Take a look at this picture: http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2O/nX/1rxyhDlU/picture20140928110951jpg.png

Comment: The white space because the widths are different. You could make it black or take the smaller of the widths for the combined picture. As about the orientation. At forehand you do not know the orientation. So I think you have to give the user the possibility to rotate both pictures independently.

Comment: How I can rotate both pictures to portrait?

Comment: Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
 bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),    bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

Comment: If I rotate both pictures in that way, that would probably will go out of the memory.

Comment: Why? And if you do you do it one by one. Independently. The user should initiate the rotalion.

Comment: I have tried it and I get this error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Where did you place the code and which bitmap did you use?

Comment: Below this line for back camera:         backBitmap = decodeBitampFromByte(data, 0, 800, 800);   
Same goes for front camera.

Comment: On what kind of device? How much memory has it? You can test and develop further by first changing 800,800 to 100,100 maybe.

Comment: It Samsung Galaxy S2. Yeah, I know that, but 100x100 it's just too small. Interesting thing that when I save image from back Camera locally to folder and open it its in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `comboImage.drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth, 0f, null);` to

```
comboImage.drawBitmap(s, 0f,c.getHeigh, null);
```